# Hide div class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

How to hide div section in step 3. i.e when clicking edit button 2nd time before editing 1st data, i want to hide 1st div.
I tried with  $(".idOfDIV").hide(); but it will hide div and while clicking Edit , I cant see any div section.
 please help me out

```
<div class="idOfDiv" ><input style="display:none;" name="textbox"  id="txtDesignation' + count+ '" class="form"   />
<a  style="display:none" onclick="Save(' + count+ ');"  id="anchSave' + count+ '"  class="but1">Save</a><input type="hidden" id="hdnMaterial' + count+ '"  /><input type="hidden" id="hdnRequestMapid' + count+ '"  />
<a  style="display:none" onclick="Cancel(' + count+ ');" id="anchcancel' + count+ '"  class="but2">Cancel</a>





function Edit(id) 
{
        $(".idOfDIV").hide(); 
        document.getElementById('anchSave' + id).style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById('anchcancel' + id).style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById('txtDesignation' + id).style.display = "inline-block";
 }
```

I have one text box ,save and cancel anchor tags inside div. ....

Comment: Code, snippet? what did you try so far? how does the html look like?

Comment: `$(".idOfDIV").hide()` will hide all elements of class `idOfDIV`, you need to use `#` to identify a single element with id `idOfDiv`, i.e. `$("#idOfDIV").hide()`

Comment: function Edit(id)
{
$(".idOfDIV").hide();
        document.getElementById('txtRqrdQty' + id).style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById('txtDesignation' + id).style.display = "inline-block";
       
}

Comment: Could you give us an example of how the divs are nested and named? If there is a certain pattern, you could simply hide all, and then show the new one (could be slow), or keep al list of visible objects and hide all objects in that list.

Comment: @IMRUP Edit your question and add the code there. Also, provide the HTML.

Comment: I used the same $(".idOfDIV").hide()  for some other function. It was working fine. But in this case its not working as expected

Comment: Jonast92 I want to hide elements of div class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using outer div for hiding. By hiding particular textbox's class like bellow

```
$(".classofTextbox").hide();
 $(".classofSave").hide();
 $(".classofCancel).hide();
 document.getElementById('txtDesignation' + id).style.display = "inline-block";
 document.getElementById('anchSave' + id).style.display = "inline-block";
 document.getElementById('anchcancel' + id).style.display = "inline-block";
```

Its working properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, "." is the selector for class. To select by ID you should use "#". So try

```
$("#idOfDIV").hide();
```

It probably worked before because your div had the same class and id :)

Comment: I want to hide elements of div class.

Comment: Then I need to see more code to know what's going on, specifically where you have defined your div (in HTML) and the exact call to the jQuery selector. Also, you might want to place an alert right at the beginning of the function to make sure it actually gets called, such as "alert('in Edit with id '+id);", javascript is tricky like that.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`(an array-like object) of all elements matching the class name. The `style` property is defined for `Element` not for `HTMLCollection`. You should access the first element using the bracket(subscript) notation.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('yourDivClass')[0].style.visibility='hidden';
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rb7bn/208/)**

Comment: By using $(".idOfDIV").hide(); i can hide. But when clicking Edit anchor it should hide previous div and it should show new div

Comment: Could you please make a `jsfiddle `of your current code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you want to hide a specific div but you are using `$(".idOfDIV").hide();` wich will hide all the divs with the class `idOfDIV` and that's why you can't see any div if you click on the button.

You should give every div a unique id, so you can show and hide it specifically, try to:

- Give every div a unique id.
- Then pass this id as a param to your function so it will hide only
  this div.

And in order to show or hide your text box and the save and cancel anchors you just need to show/hide their parent div, and they will be shown or hidden with it.

```
function Edit(id) 
{ 
 $("#"+id).hide(); 
}
```